# Can I extend a network by connecting two Modems via a RG-6 coax cable? Assuming I have normal routers on either end?

Tags: networking, internet, modem, wireless-extender

The flow of Data would be as follows: ISP --> Modem 0 --> Router 0  As would be in a normal home internet setup.

Then LAN 0 from Router 0 --> *(Via Ethernet)* --> Modem 1 WAN

**Modem 1 ==> *(Via Coax)* ==> Modem 2**

Modem 2 --> *(Via Ethernet)* --> Router 1 WAN

Router 1 LAN --> *(Via Ethernet)* --> Computer 1

I already have the equipment and the cable is already ran between two outbuildings. The modems I have are Arris Surfboards SB6121's.

I assume this is completely possible on a physical level? But, that it might not be possible *for me* to do with these modems themselves. Has anyone tried to do this? Or is there some special software that ISP's/manufacturers use to assign the correct privileges/settings to these consumer level products? I saw in another answer you could use a MoCA converter, but that's not what I'm really interested in, I would just use radios/repeaters if I wanted a cheap work around.

Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: No. Cable modems take coax as input and Ethernet as output. You are trying to operate the modem backwards :)

Comment: Kind of? :) But since I've got a modem at each end, I would be uploading at one end, and downloading at the other, with the modem making the correct serial conversions between itself. Kind of like a radio, but instead of wireless, it's wired.

Comment: Yes, but that's not how cable modems work. They require a CTMS (Cable Modem Termination System) at the ISP which sends the appropriate data to the Cable Modem to provide an internet connection. So connecting two cable modems just doesn't work.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was wondering and couldn't find an answer to. :) If you don't mind my asking, what type of hardware is required to deploy a CTMS?

Comment: [Cable modem termination system - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem_termination_system)

Comment: Haha literally reading that now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that there _are_ other technologies such as MoCA and G.hn which work over the same kind of coax and are made specifically for home use. (But you will need new different hardware.) Someone else will have more experience with these.